# A Database Error Occurred Duplicate entry '119867-en_GB' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to insert data from my page to a database , and i get this error

```
<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
        <p>Error Number: 1062</p><p>Duplicate entry '119867-en_GB' for key 'PRIMARY'</p><p>INSERT INTO `ProjectTableName` (`id`, `lang`, `name`) VALUES (119867, 'en_GB', 'test data')</p><p>Filename: models/modelFileLocation.php</p><p>Line Number: 48</p>   </div>
```

Here is my code in the model  for insertion of data to the database

```
$this->db->insert('ProjectTableName', array('id' => $table_id,
                                          'lang' => $lang,
                                          'name' => $name));
```

How can i be able to solve this error , am using codeignter 3

Comment: The problem is you try to insert a value with same value ('119867-en_GB' ) on PRIMARY key

Comment: I edited it and it was still same . That value was not existent in the database.

Answer (score 0):

you not need to send id in the insert array. remove it from the array and make it auto increment in the database. Just use the below code

```
$this->db->insert('ProjectTableName', array(
                                      'lang' => $lang,
                                      'name' => $name));
```

Comment: i have edited it , and removed the id , they send me another error call to undefined method 

Call to undefined method Company::change_amount() /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projectname/application/controllers/Company.php

//After account creation, insert the balance values
  foreach ($balances as $balance) {
   $data = [
    'account_id' => '#',
    'balance' => $balance->balance,
    'chart_id' => $chart_of_accounts_id,
    'new_value' => $balance->account->amount,
   ];
   $this->change_amount((object) $data);
  }
 }

Comment: could you please add your complete code it will easy to understand then.

Comment: Try this link for the full code

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QZHhtoYJA8QCiRiKtU3LnRhNxuW_GRlaU1ehBxHvfbg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the error is due to the function change_amount is not created. Where did you create this function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that data is returned, you can also use these codes,

```
$data = [
    'lang' => $lang,
    'name' => $name,
];

$this->db->set($data)->insert('ProjectTableName');

if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

The number of columns interacting in this way will return, and if true is greater than 0, it will return true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your problem is definitely caused by what I wrote below.

The 'lang' field in the table is selected as 'primary key' and the primary key fields accept only one of the data.

The right example

```
lang
----
 a
 b
 c
 d
```

If your table situation is this and wrong

```
lang
----
 a -> 1
 a -> 2
 c
 d
```

cannot contain two 'a' data in the primary key field, specify an id instead and set it as primary key. there is a repetitive entry in the primary key field as the error says.

Good work ..